# Cross platform file names in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filesystems, cross-platform

I have an input field in which file name is being inserted by user. Then the file with this name is being created. The problem is in difference between file systems on different OS.  On user side I have a javascript regexp. Here it is:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z\^\&\'\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\.\%\+\~\_ ]{1,228}$/
```

It only allows alphanumeric characters and specified symbols to be used. Also I need my server  side code to try to create file (like touch command in UNIX/LINUX OS) and handle errors if there are any. How can I do that on Ruby? Is there a better solution for cross platform product?

Comment: Do you really need to use their chosen file name? Couldn't you just store their name in your database and choose whatever file name is convenient?

Comment: I am not the one who makes decisions :)

Comment: You don't escape all those special chars when they are in a character class (in other words: /^[\w^&'@{}\[\],$=!#().%+~_ -]{1,228}$/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem with catching exception when file name is invalid and printing it for user.

```
begin
     touch_file = open("#{@base_dir}#{file_name}", 'w')
     if touch_file
        #here goes code for opening file and inserting some text into it
     end
     rescue Exception => msg
          #here I return msg.message to user

 end
```